# Get route name given my current url

Tags: php, laravel-4

I would like to ask if there's a way or a laravel helper to know my current route name?

for example I'm using a REST request such as localhost:8081/user/1/edit
then I want to know my current route name.

ofcourse my route name is '/user/{id}/edit'

so when I am comparing my current url to that route.

Let us say I have a pass variable to a certain class, knowing my own route as

`$url = '/user/{id}/edit';`

From my blade template

```
@if (URL::current() == URL::to($url))
  // this will fail because URL::current() is equal to /user/1/edit
@endif
```

If there's no way to do this, I'm planning to create a preg_match instead.

My purpose on doing this is that, I am creating my own package that handles routes with custom filters, for me to do that, I need to wrap all the list of routes inside that callback Route class.

Such as:

```
Route::{$process}($url, function($params_preg_matched) {
   // Some Filtering Here
   // Some Redirections Here.
});
```

It's hard for me to explain why I am doing this, because I am doing something new.

If you wan't to check my github project, here it is:
https://github.com/daison12006013/daison-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath()`

So further more, `echo URL::to(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath())` so that you can match a certain URL, alternative using `URL::to()` when using callback/functional routes with RESTful request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know clearly may you can try this  [ref](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes)

```
$name = Route::currentRouteName();
$url = URL::route($name);
```

Comment: I forgot to include that I'm using route functions instead of named routes.